# End2End Encryption on Orbeon 2017.1 Forms

Tags: orbeon

Because of the data protection law regarding health data, we are currently required to implement an additional End2End encrypting over TLS. As our application forms are over Orbeon 2017.1 (along with Hybris), For the last couple of days, we have been investigating possible encryption options in Orbeon.

In Orbeon 2018, there is Field-level encryption: https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/field-level-encryption

However, even that feels like not we are looking for, as it is "encrypting data at rest" and not "encrypting at transit".

Are there any ways to encrypt data at transit in Orbeon (over TLS)? If not, what are the possible implementation approaches for such a use case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to encrypt data in transit:

- Between the browser and the server – This has become a must for pretty much any website, and is something that you would configure at the level of your application server or servlet container (e.g. Tomcat), or reverse proxy sitting in front of that server (e.g. IIS or Apache HTTP Server).
- Between your application server or servlet container and your database – This is done less frequently, and would typically be a feature provided by your database and its JDBC driver.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding your points, (if I understood correctly) we are already encrypting the data in transit using SSL/TLS between browser and server and encrypting the data on database. However, due to data being sensitive, in the security audits we are asked to implement another encryption method on top of TLS. We are wondering how such a thing can be achieved with Orbeo; if there are any built-in functionalities or any suggested ways to achieve this.

Comment: @merterpam Could tell me more about the specifics of that requirement to implement "another encryption method on top of TLS"? I don't remember ever coming across such a requirement, and can't really make sense of it either, at least without additional information.

Comment: According to the regulations in Germany (or at least in Bayern), health data is considered as an 'extra' sensitive data and that is why 'extra' security measures needs to be taken care of during transmission of such data. According to a report released (https://www.lda.bayern.de/media/baylda_report_07.pdf), they require an additional end-to-end encryption (eg PGP with 4096-bit) in addition to TLS.

Comment: We also never came across such a requirement and are not able to understand the meaning behind it very well, but according to our security audit from a trusted 3rd party, we are required to implement it. We are also still trying to clarify this issue, however according to the 3rd Party, this encyrption is necessary due to the possible exploits in TLS. We are also trying to clarify it to figure out what kind of attack scenarios are considered for such an encryption, however at the same time we are also investigating how to change our current implementation to fit the regulation.

Comment: @merterpam Thank you for the link, but I am not familiar enough with German to go through that documentation. My suspicion is that this applies to other means of communication with the customer, like email, as I've never heard about PGP being used to encrypt content in web apps. And if HTTPS wasn't secure, our banks wouldn't allow us to perform transactions over it ;).

Comment: PGP is just an example, but so far the requirement still stay the same. And I totally agree, from a developer perspective, saying HTTPS is not secure doesn't really make sense, however this is the current requirement (based on the regulation) that is passed to us... Do you have any idea/directions about how we can implement it custom by effecting the Orbeon as little as possible? Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: To clarify the need from technical perspective, the explanation that is given to us is the following: Due to exploits of TLS, it is rarely possible for data to be sniffed and read rawly by an attacker. In such cases, the health data that is sent should not be readable by attacker, hence needing a content-wise encryption of sent data on top of TLS. The main purpose of this encryption is for confidentiality.

Comment: @merterpam If we're talking about communication between the webserver and the browser, there are cases where you can encrypt data sent to the browser because you don't want users to see it; the data is just sent to the browser so the browser can send it back to the server, as an alternative to keeping it on the server. But if users need to be able to see it, I don't see what else you can do in addition to HTTPS. But if someone has this as a requirement, I imagine that they should be able to point to at least one example where it was done in the past. So I'd start by asking for an example.

Comment: @merterpam Just curious, if this is still on your plate, did you get a chance to ask those who came up with this requirement for example of web app where this was done?

Comment: Sorry I missed the last message. Although the encryption from webserver to browser is also a question (at this direction, proposed solutions were a lot more complicated), the initial focus was on the encryption from browser  to webserver. Fraunhofer claims that there are some insurance companies that implement this, but.. we are still a bit skeptical about it. The topic is for now escalated to upper layers and it will take some time before it becomes the focus of developers again (but maybe another of our team's focus)

Comment: Got it @merterpam, thank you for the update. I am skeptical as well ;). And of course, you'll let us know if/when there is something about this, especially if you think that it would make sense to implement the scheme in question in Orbeon Forms.